# How to get_available_languages in views.py

Tags: django, django-i18n

I am trying to get in my `views.py` a list of all the languages I have available.

This is easily done in a template through the tag

`{% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}` ([docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/translation/#get-available-languages)), but I do not find its equivalent for the views.

Is there any simple way to get it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
from django.conf import settings

settings.LANGUAGES
```

anyways you have to config [`LANGUAGES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#languages) in settings before like this:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

LANGUAGES = [
    ('de', _('German')),
    ('en', _('English')),
]
```

Comment: A simple loop over the `settings.LANGAUAGES`  also is what happens in the `get_available_languages` [template tag](https://github.com/django/django/blob/35d36d946272bed06a3d7c7cd4e5b71b613e7a4f/django/templatetags/i18n.py#L16).